# How to set icons in `LineChart` to selected position in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a list of Entry points which I have plotted on LineChart. Now I want to set icon to a particular point. How to set or draw icons in `LineChart` to my selected position in MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add icon to your selected point using 3 parameters `Entry` constructor where third parameter is a `Drawable`:

public **Entry**(float x,  float y, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon)

**Parameters:**
x - the x value
y - the y value (the actual value of the entry)
icon - icon image

[Ref: MPAndroidChart v3.0.3 JavaDoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.3/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/Entry.html#Entry-float-float-android.graphics.drawable.Drawable-)

Example:

```
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    values.add(new Entry (x, y, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.star)));
```

You can mark a single point with icon from entire `LineDataSet` by adding `Drawable` in `Entry` constructor.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I added entries with icon but it's not shown.
Should I add something else like : setDrawIcons(true) ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but This is my solution in case anyone still needs it.

First, you need to call `setDrawIcons(true)` on your data set. Then You need to define your entry as a member inside your class to be able to reset it later.

```
private var selectedEntry: Entry? = null
```

And Inside `onValueSelected` you need to set `selectedEntry's` icon as null if it exists and set the icon for the new `selectedEntry` point.

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
    if (selectedEntry != null) {
        selectedEntry?.icon = null
    }
    for (set in chart.data.dataSets) {
        selectedEntry = set.getEntryForIndex(set.getEntryIndex(e))
        selectedEntry?.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.star)
    }
    chart.invalidate()
}
```